# Window frozen shut

Tags: window

Its freakin cold outside.  I wanted to put my window down a little so I could smoke.  However, the driver's window was frozen shut.  All the other windows are fine.  This in itself isnt all that interesting, but what makes it interesting is the fact that this is not the first time this has happened.  Not only that, its not the only car this has happened in.  Im not sure if this is coincidence, or if there is a reason for it.

Any ideas why its only the drivers side window that gets frozen shut and not the others?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Total Guess**

It's very cold.

You drive around.

You roll down your window to smoke.

Moisture from respiration builds up on the edge of the window while you smoke.

You roll your window up.

Moisture is trapped between your window and the rubber insulation.

You park and go inside.

The window freezes to the surface of the insulation.

Comment: thats what i was thinking...  didnt think there would be enough moisture though...

Comment: im gonna go with this answer...  feel free to add other thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that it's because the weatherstripping around the driver side window is more worn because it gets used more than the other windows. Since it's more worn, it may be letting water get by, which then freezes. Replacing the weatherstripping may be an easy do-it-yourself job, depending on your car.

Comment: its possible...